# Javascript Nested Function - Need help returning result

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I am trying to create a function to return a lat/long array from the Google Maps JS API (v3). I am able to write the data out that I retrieve from the API, but I am not able to pass the data along to a variable. I am wanting to do something like this:

```
var latLong = getLatLong(Address);
```

The function that I have created is here:

```
function getLatLong(loc, callback) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var array = new Array();

  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': loc }, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;;
        $.each(latLng, function(k, v) {
          if (k == 'va' || k == 'wa') {
            array.push(v);
          }
        });
        var ret = array;
        callback(ret);
      } else {
        console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I then am assigning the function to a variable and calling it to give me the lat/long.

```
var geo = getLatLong('Dallas, TX', function(result) {
  return result;
});
```

Unfortunately this produces an 'undefined' result. I can access the result in the function, I just can't pass it along. How can I pass the result of the function to a variable to be accessed?

Comment: did you mean you need a return somewere?

Answer (score 3):

> Unfortunately this produces an 'undefined' result

Do you mean in the 'geo' variable? If so, you are missing the point of callbacks. The function you pass in will be called *later* after the getLatLong() call returns. Callbacks are asynchronous functions, and you will want to use the callback to take an action (e.g. change state, tweak a display, etc.) of your choice.

Try changing it to

```
function(result) { alert('callback result: '+result); }
```

to check if it gets called properly. If you get an `alert()` properly, then you might want to do something like this:

```
var geo = null;
getLatLong('Dallas, TX', function(result) {
   // cache state
   geo = result;
   // do something with it
   showResultInSomeSpotOnThePage(result);
});
/* We can't use the "geo" variable contents immediately
 * after getLatLong returns; it will be set at some time later.
 * But there may be some use for keeping the result around indefinitely,
 * we just have to be prepared for "geo" to be null if we check it
 * before the callback is called.
 */
```

Comment: well said. clear example. the comment at the end of your example is key. +1

Comment: The callback I was using was the result of my frustration in trying to return the lat/long to a variable. I was trying to be creative! :-)

Comment: TThanks for the great example! My thought was that there should be some way to return the result to a variable. I guess I'm just going to have to use a callback to do what I'm wanting.

Comment: @Jason: You *can* store the result in a variable, it's just that to do so directly via your getLatLong function's return value, you'd have to block = busy-wait, and that's either bad form (if the Javascript interpreter is multithreaded) or impossible (if it's single-threaded). Asynchronous calls just take some getting used to. It's a common idiom in Javascript; see setInterval or setTimeout. (and start to learn about closures)

Answer (score 3):

You can't structure the code the way you want to here.  The problem is that `geocoder.geocode()` is an *asynchronous operation*.  That's why it takes a callback function.  When you call `geocoder.geocode()`, it *initiates* the request to fetch the geocode, and then returns, leaving the request running in the background.  When the request eventually completes, google's api will execute the anonymous function you passed as the second parameter to `geocode()`.

So when you call `getLatLong()` the actual order that things happen is something like this:

1. call `geocoder.geocode()`.  (initiates geocode request)
2. `getLatLong()` is done and returns undefined. (this is where `geo` gets set)
3. (the geocode request completes) google api calls the anonymous function, which pushes the LatLng values into `array`, and then calls your `callback()`

to better visualize what's going on, you might write your code as follows (this is exactly equivalent to the way you've written it):

```
function getLatLong(loc, callback) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var array = new Array();

  function handleGeocodeResponse(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;;
      $.each(latLng, function(k, v) {
        if (k == 'va' || k == 'wa') {
          array.push(v);
        }
      });
      var ret = array;
      callback(ret);
    }
  }

  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': loc }, handleGeocodeResponse);
  } else {
    console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
  }

  // note- no return specified explicitly is the same as
  //return undefined;
}
```

---

So, if you can't return a value, then how do you use the results?  Like this:

```
getLatLong('Dallas, TX', function(geo) {
  // geo is passed to this function as a parameter
  // move all code that requires `geo` into this function.

});
```

Comment: I really like the way you defined the order of events. I was thinking there would be a way to return the results to a variable in some fashion. Due to the asynchronous nature of the call, I can see that's not going to be possible. I'm just going to do the callback and let that function work it's magic. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is that `getLatLong` doesn't return a value. That is why `geo` is always undefined.

To make this work, you'll need to modify your callback function. Something like this:

```
getLatLong('Dallas, TX', function(result)
{
    var geo = result; 
    //continue to use geo here as you normally would
});
```

Comment: getLatLong can't return a value unless either google's geocoder.geocode returns a value, or there is a blocking (=bad!) call to await geocoder.geocode's completion.

Comment: The key issue is actually the asynchronous nature of the geocode call, your examples suggest that `geo` will contain a usable value immediately following the call to `getLatLong()` ... which is not true at all.  As a result, this confuses the issue further, rather than clarifying it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback guys, you've helped me understand this much better! I've removed the inaccurate parts of my answer.
+1 for both :)

Answer (score 0):

geo is undefined because getLatLong() doesn't return anything (which means it returns undefined).

Comment: so you probably want to write "return callback(ret);" in getLatLong()

Comment: he can't `return callback(ret)` since `ret` is not obtained until Google's geocoder API calls the callback.

Comment: yes, but the core issue is that the asynchronous result of `geocoder.geocode()`, can't be returned synchronously from the OP's `getLatLong()` function.